# Selecting customer addresses with radio inputs and knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an address selection screen. Address data are coming from server. Data covers these values:

- `Id` = Address Id,
- `Address` = Address itself,
- `TypeCode` = 1 or 2 (1 is shipping, 2 is billing address),
- `IsDefault` = boolean (is this default address)

I map these data in two arrays. One of them contains shipping addresses and the other one billing addresses.

I have couple of problems.

1. I can't set default addresses when server data comes.
2. When I want to set a new address I click another radio button. When I do that I gave two address id's in "`selectedShippingAddress`" loop. I think this is not the right way to do this.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/sevilyilmaz/HnGS4/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `checked` binding wrong way. It doesn't point to property of object which should  be selected, it points to observable which has ID of selected object. i.e.:  `checked: $parent.selectedShippingAddres` and `selectedShippingAddres = ko.observable();`. Now when you populate your data in `updateAddresses` you can check and save the default ID:

```
$.map(data.AddressListItems, function (v) {
  if (v.TypeCode === 1) {
    viewModel.shippingAddresses.push(v);
    if (v.IsDefault) {
      viewModel.selectedShippingAddress(v.Id);
    }
  } else {
    viewModel.billingAddresses.push(v);
    if (v.IsDefault) {
      viewModel.selectedBillingAddress(v.Id);
    }
  }
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/HnGS4/4/